# Set Hashtag for FacebookShareDialog

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing an Android app that let user share the photo to facebook, so I use FacebookDialog for my app.
I followed the [Facebook developer guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android) and I tried to set Hashtag for the sharing, but the FacebookDialog is pop-up without Hashtag.
Code

```
image = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContext().getContentResolver(), descriptionPhotoUri);
SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
    .setBitmap(image)
    .build();
SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
    .setShareHashtag(new ShareHashtag.Builder().setHashtag(Constants.APPLICATION_HASHTAG).build())
    .addPhoto(photo)
    .build();
facebookShareDialog.show(content, ShareDialog.Mode.AUTOMATIC);
```

Build grade:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
```

[image]
Is there any way to set Hashtag for sharing content using facebookdialog.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Constants.APPLICATION_HASHTAG is like "#Aiuspaktyn" ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: No, I did not..

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                   .setBitmap(image)
                   .build(); 

ShareContent shareContent = new ShareMediaContent.Builder()
                    .addMedium(photo)
                    .setShareHashtag(new ShareHashtag.Builder()
                            .setHashtag("#Whatever")
                            .build())
                    .build();
```

It works for me, the difference is that you use `new SharePhotoContent.Builder()` instead `new ShareMediaContent.Builder()`.

Hope it helps.